# Looping through each file in directory - bash

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, grep

I'm trying to perform certain operation on each file in a directory but there is a problem with order it's going through. It should do one file at the time. The long line (unzipping, grepping, zipping) works fine on a single file without a script, so there is a problem with a loop. Any ideas?

Script should grep through through each zipped file and look for word1 or word2. If at least one of them exist then:

1. unzip file
2. grep word1 and word2 and save it to file_done
3. remove unzipped file
4. zip file_done to /donefiles/ with original name
5. remove file_done from original directory

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for file in *.gz; do
    counter=$(zgrep -c 'word1\|word2' $file)
    if [[  $counter -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo $counter
    for file in *.gz; do
    filenoext=${file::-3}
    filedone=${filenoext}_done
    echo $file
    echo $filenoext
    echo $filedone
    gunzip  $file | grep 'word1\|word2'  $filenoext > $filedone | rm -f $filenoext |  gzip -f  -c  $filedone > /donefiles/$file | rm -f $filedone
    done
    else
    echo "nothing to do here"
    fi
    done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snipped you've provided has a few problems, e.g. unneeded nested for cycle and erroneous pipeline
(the whole line `gunzip  $file | grep 'word1\|word2'  $filenoext > $filedone | rm -f $filenoext |  gzip...`).

Note also your code will work correctly only if *.gz files don't have spaces (or special characters) in names.
Also `zgrep -c 'word1\|word2'` will also match strings like `line_starts_withword1_orword2_`.

Here is the working version of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.gz; do
        counter=$(zgrep -c -E 'word1|word2' $file) # now counter is the number of word1/word2 occurences in $file
        if [[ $counter -gt 0 ]]; then
                name=$(basename $file .gz)
                zcat $file | grep -E 'word1|word2' > ${name}_done
                gzip -f -c ${name}_done > /donefiles/$file
                rm -f ${name}_done
        else
                echo 'nothing to do here'
        fi
done
```

What we can improve here is:

- since we unzipping the file anyway to check for word1|word2 presence, we may do this to temp file and avoid double-unzipping
- we don't need to count how many word1 or word2 is inside the file, we may just check for their presence
- ${name}_done can be a temp file cleaned up automatically
- we can use while cycle to handle file names with spaces

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp=`mktemp /tmp/gzip_demo.XXXXXX` # create temp file for us
trap "rm -f \"$tmp\"" EXIT INT TERM QUIT HUP # clean $tmp upon exit or termination
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name '*.gz' | while read f; do
        # quotes around $f are now required in case of spaces in it
        s=$(basename "$f") # short name w/o dir
        gunzip -f -c "$f" | grep -P '\b(word1|word2)\b' > "$tmp"
        [ -s "$tmp" ] && gzip -f -c "$tmp" > "/donefiles/$s" # create archive if anything is found
done
```

Comment: Don't forget to add double quotes around variables expansion or file names with spaces tabs or newlines will fail `counter=$(zgrep -c -E 'word1|word2' $file)` → `counter=$(zgrep -c -E 'word1|word2' "$file")` and since return status of `grep` reveal if pattern found, then just do `if zgrep -qcE 'word1|word2' "$file"; then name=${file%.gz}` ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an inner loop inside the outer one :

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.gz; do
    counter=$(zgrep -c 'word1\|word2' $file)
    if [[  $counter -gt 0 ]]; then
        echo $counter
        for file in *.gz; do #<<< HERE
            filenoext=${file::-3}
            filedone=${filenoext}_done
            echo $file
            echo $filenoext
            echo $filedone
            gunzip  $file | grep 'word1\|word2'  $filenoext > $filedone | rm -f $filenoext |  gzip -f  -c  $filedone > /donefiles/$file | rm -f $filedone
        done
    else
        echo "nothing to do here"
    fi
done
```

The inner loop goes through all the files in the directory if one of them contains file1 or file2. You probably want this :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.gz; do
    counter=$(zgrep -c 'word1\|word2' $file)
    if [[  $counter -gt 0 ]]; then
        echo $counter
        filenoext=${file::-3}
        filedone=${filenoext}_done
        echo $file
        echo $filenoext
        echo $filedone
        gunzip  $file | grep 'word1\|word2'  $filenoext > $filedone | rm -f $filenoext |  gzip -f  -c  $filedone > /donefiles/$file | rm -f $filedone
    else
        echo "nothing to do here"
    fi
done
```